# How to check OS and version using a Linux command

Tags: linux, shell

What is the Linux command to check the server OS and its version?

I am connected to the server using shell.

Answer (score 487, accepted):

### Kernel Version

If you want kernel version information, use uname(1). For example:

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.11.0-3-generic #8-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 23 16:49:15 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Distribution Information

If you want distribution information, it will vary depending on your distribution and whether your system supports the [Linux Standard Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base). Some ways to check, and some example output, are immediately below.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Saucy Salamander (development branch)
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy

$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=saucy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Saucy Salamander (development branch)"

$ cat /etc/issue.net
Ubuntu Saucy Salamander (development branch)

$ cat /etc/debian_version 
wheezy/sid
```

Comment: CodeGnome, why not use `uname -o`

Comment: @debal Because on Linux systems all it returns is `GNU/Linux`, which is not what the OP is likely asking for.

Comment: Just checked it, and you are correct. `lsb_release -a` did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I tried cat /etc/issue and it gives me result as: \S Kernel \r on an \m, what does it mean?

Comment: @Ray, get the same for CentOS 7, issue.net for Red Hat case is used to identify the format of print out message. \r for "Inset the release number", \m for "insert the architecture identifier of the machine".

Comment: Just to add, hostnamectl is also an option.

Answer (score 78):

If it is a debian based system, you could do

```
cat /etc/*_version
```

or for a Red Hat or CentOS based system, you could try (this is working on Red Hat Enterprise Linux-7):

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

Comment: `cat /etc/*-release` - works for me. I have `/etc/alpine-release` and `/etc/os-release`.

Comment: Also works for CentOS

Comment: Yes! This gave me Rocky Linux 8.7 (Green Obsidian)", while the accepted answer couldn’t.

Answer (score 74):

You can execute `cat /etc/redhat-release` to check the [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) (RH) version if you use an RH-based OS.

Another solution that may work on any linux distributions is `lsb_release -a`.

And the `uname -a` command shows the kernel version and other things.

Also `cat /etc/issue.net` shows your OS version... This file shows in the telnet command when you want to connect to the server. For security reasons, it is better to delete the version and os name in this file.

Comment: "cat /etc/issue.net" works on Raspberry Pi. For example, "Raspbian GNU/Linux 7"

Comment: Telnet? I thought it was ssh these days(?)