# ipinfo: command not found on Linux VM, how do I install the package?

Tags: linux, package-management, virtual-machine, ip, command

I'm using a Linux VM on my Chromebook and I simply entered `ipinfo` and the command can't be found in any directory.

So I figured I would need to install it and entered :

```
sudo apt install ipinfo
```

and got

```
 E: unable to locate package ipinfo
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which distribution is installed on that VM? (Debian, Ubuntu, Slack, Arch, SUSE, Fedora ...) - And what / where do you get the idea to install `ipinfo` (As in what is it). There are various different projects using this *name*.

Comment: It's not an official Linux Distro, it's Chrome's integrated Linux development environment (beta) that can be turned on with the Chrome OS (version 9 or higher).  The window that opens is the same app that opens the Crosh terminal but to open the app as is, it'll run this Linux VM with MyUserName@penguin:~$ at the command line.  It doesn't seem to know certain commands like nano.  I probably should just find the time to dual boot my Chromebook with the Chrome OS and Xubuntu, so I can switch between the two as necessary.

Comment: Ah. OK. But the dev thing uses `apt` package manager, so perhaps some Debian derivative? Form what I read Chrome-OS is Gentoo based and uses Portage. I do not know Chrome OS, and am at a loss. Strange one have to install Linux on a Linux system to get Linux tools ... but it is perhaps too far from Linux to be Linux heh. *Anyhow:* what package is it you are trying to install? Where do you have it from? As you already have found, there is no package named `ipinfo` in `apt` ... Perhaps switch the X/Y and state what you want to do :), and there is perhaps another package to do what you want.

Comment: You can check out this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88647/140633 , and run command(s) in your Linux shell.